# Clicking on WebPart modifies page layout

Tags: custom, page-layout, content-editor-web-part

I'm building a custom dashboard with some CEWP's and List webparts, using a three column page layout. Whenever I interact with (click) one of the columns, it adjusts the layout. In this particular case, I have a table that has a width of 100%, so normally it fills the column, which takes up 33% of the page, but upon clicking, the column shifts down below the rest of the content and fills 100% of the page.

How can I disable whatever is happening, or what do I need to do to avoid this?